# Is there a way to make a raster image from the Google Maps Basemap in QGIS? I need an RGB satellite image for my study area

Tags: gis, raster, qgis, matplotlib-basemap, satellite-image

Is there a way to make a raster image from the Google Maps Base map in QGIS? I need an RGB satellite image for my study area.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the google base map to QGIS, and if you want to have the image locally in your computer use this tool [24.1.12.1. Convert map to raster](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rastertools.html#convert-map-to-raster).

Here's how you can add the google base map in qgis [Adding Basemaps from Google or Bing in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis)